# How to get ASP.NET Core MVC Filters from HttpContext

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, httpcontext, asp.net-core-middleware

I'm trying to write some middleware and need to know if the current action method (if any) has a particular filter attribute, so I can change behaviour based it's existence.

So is it possible to get a filters collection of type `IList<IFilterMetadata>` like you do on the `ResourceExecutingContext` when you are implementing an `IResourceFilter`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

<strike>It's not really possible today.</strike>

It is possible in ASP.NET Core 3.0

```
app.UseRouting();


app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
    Endpoint endpoint = context.GetEndpoint();

    YourFilterAttribute filter = endpoint.Metadata.GetMetadata<YourFilterAttribute>();

    if (filter != null)
    { 

    }

    await next();
});


app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllers();
});
```

Comment: Is this now possible in ASP.NET Core 3.0? In particular, I have a `RewriteContext` from the response rewrite middleware.

Answer (score 5):

ASP.NET Core 3.0 uses a new routing which every action is an `Endpoint` and all attributes on the action and the controller exists on `Metadata`.

Here's how you can do it.

```
app.UseRouting();


app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
    Endpoint endpoint = context.GetEndpoint();

    YourFilterAttribute filter = endpoint.Metadata.GetMetadata<YourFilterAttribute>();

    if (filter != null)
    { 

    }

    await next();
});


app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllers();
});
```

Comment: This is the same exact code from the prior post (which you edited to contain that) so is now a duplicate answer

Answer (score 0):

*Note: Not really answering directly your question, but may help depending of your needs (and the code is too long for comments)*

*Note 2: Not sure if it works on Core, if it doesn't, tell me and I remove the answer*

You can know, in a filter, if another filter is used along with:

```
public class OneFilter : ActionFilterAttribute, IActionFilter
{
    void IActionFilter.OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        // Check if the Attribute "AnotherFilter" is used
        if (filterContext.ActionDescriptor.IsDefined(typeof(AnotherFilter), true) || filterContext.Controller.GetType().IsDefined(typeof(AnotherFilter), true))
        {
            // things to do if the filter is used

        }
    }
}

public class AnotherFilter : ActionFilterAttribute, IActionFilter
{
   // filter things
}
```

AND/OR

You can put some data in the Route data to let know the Action which Filters are used:

```
void IActionFilter.OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
{
    filterContext.RouteData.Values.Add("OneFilterUsed", "true");
    base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
}
```

...

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    if(RouteData.Values["OneFilterUsed"] == "true")
    {

    }

    return View();
}
```

Comment: `IsDefined` doesn't exist in .Net Core's ActionDescriptor.

Comment: Yeap, there is no `IsDefined()`, but the following can be used: `if (filterContext.Filters.Any(x => filters.Contains(typeof(AnotherFilter)));`) { // things to do... }